# Set grand total in cart page Magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento, magento2, cart, checkout

Each Customer has few points in their account. 1 point = 1 Rupee.
I want to give a textbox and a button in a cart page when the customer enters the points in the text box I want to subtract that points with the grand total and update the grand total.

With the below code I can get the grand total

```
$cartQuote = $this->cart->getQuote();
error_log($cartQuote->getGrandTotal());
```

But I'm not able to set the grand total

```
$grandTotal = "200";
$cartQuote->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
$this->quoteRepository->save($cartQuote);
```

I know all other logic and flow I just want to update the grand total

Could anyone please help to update the grand total

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set custom subtotal and grand total with use of below model class

```
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total 

$grandtotal = 100;
$total->setGrandTotal($grandtotal);
$total->setBaseGrandTotal($grandtotal);
```

After that, you need to perform below commands.

1. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
2. php bin/magento index:reindex
3. php bin/magento cache:flush

You know the logic so, I am not mentioning other details.

For More details check this: [Change Order Total](https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-pricefee-order-total-magento2/)